# What's the difference between passing parameters to view function from html tag in Flask?

Tags: flask, jinja2

My html tags: I need to pass two parameters linkNode and matchMode to the view function.

```
<a class="class2" href="{{ url_for('nlp.link', linkNode=v, matchMode=matchMode) }}">{{ v }}</a>
```

The view function:

```
@bp.route('/<linkNode>/link', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def link(linkNode):
    
    matchMode = request.args.get('matchMode')
    results = search(linkNode, 'kmatch', matchMode)
    
    return render_template('nlp/wbkg.html', items=results, query=linkNode)
```

The two syntaxes for the two parameter are the following:

```
@bp.route('/<linkNode>/link', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
```

And

```
matchMode = request.args.get('matchMode')
```

Is there any differences between the two syntaxes or methods to get parameters from template to views? Or the two are interchangeable?

Answer (score 0):

```
@bp.route('/<linkNode>/link', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
```

indicates that `linkNode` will come in as part of the URL.

```
matchMode = request.args.get('matchMode')
```

indicates that `matchMode` will come in as a parameter. E.g.,

```
/foo/link?matchMode=bar
```

will result, within `link()` with

```
linkNode = 'foo'
matchMode = 'bar'
```